# How to select specific GPUs in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gpu, nvidia

On a machine with multiple Nvidia GPUs, is there a way to specify in the `docker-compose.yml` file that we want to use two specific GPU device IDs in the Docker container?

The following seems to be the equivalent of docker run --gpus=all`since all the GPUs are listed when running`nvidia-smi` inside the Docker container.

```
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

Comment: Is this manual page helpful?
https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `device_ids` or `count`.

For example, to allow only GPUs with ID `0` and `3`:

```
deploy:
    resources:
        reservations:
            devices:
                - driver: nvidia
                  device_ids: ['0', '3']
                  capabilities: [gpu]
```

[Enabling GPU access with Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/#access-specific-devices)